# Extjs 5.1 tab order is not working in the form with dynamically created textfields

Tags: extjs5, extjs-form

I have a form that has some textfields and combos with a vbox layout. These components are created dynamically after pressing one button. The tab order seems that is not working. The cursor doesn't go from one textfield to the next one by pressing the tab. What am i missing and the tab order is not working? In case the form is declared statically as view-controller, the tab order is working automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can set tab order via [`tabIndex`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-cfg-tabIndex) property.